# Change color when changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some input elements (text, radio, checkbox, etc.) in my document. Each of them should change its color when a change is made.

This is my approach:

```
$("document").on('click', 'change', 'select', function() {
  $(this).addClass("changed")
});
```

When I change the value of my input elements, either by clicking, entering text or selecting, the background color doesn't change.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6c8q6rjk/).

Comment: __`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of errors; `document` shouldn't be in quotes as you're providing the document object to the selector, and also you should separate the events by a space in a single parameter, not two different parameters. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click change', 'select', function() {
    $(this).addClass("changed")
});
```

If you want to target any type of form control, use the `:input` selector:

```
$(document).on('click change', ':input', function() {
    $(this).addClass("changed")
});
```

See the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) for more details.

Comment: That only works with the select-boxes, but not the other input elements.

Comment: Well, that's a given as you only have selected the `select` elements. If you want to target both `input` and `select`, use `:input` in the second parameter.

Comment: @user1170330, well that would make sense given **you** specified `'select'` as the selector in the original code...

Comment: Just to make sure the OP knows, this is going to filter the events so that you only get events from a `<select>`

Answer (score 0):

Small mistake. It should be:

```
$(function () {
  $(document).on('click change', 'select, input', function() {
//-^--------^---------^^^--------------^^^^^^^^^
    $(this).addClass("changed")
  });
});
```

Also wrap it inside `document` ready function.

The syntax for [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) is:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mL823jws/**

Comment: `space` or `comma` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Er... I didn't get you, but it should be given as a single string, rather than two. That's what I was trying to tell.

Comment: My fiddle still doesn't work with your code. Do I have another mistake?

Comment: `"document"` should not be in quotes

Comment: `Event` should be separated by `space(" ")`

Comment: Directly from the documentation in [the link you provided](https://api.jquery.com/on/)... 'One or more **space-separated** event types and optional namespaces, such as "click" or "keydown.myPlugin".'

Comment: @user1170330 Updated.